# C++ , how come I do not get the value "123456"

Tags: c++

I am trying to print out value 123456, but it gives me the garbage value. How can I fix it? And Can you please explain why it gives the wrong value?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct MyInfo
{
private:
    int private_key = 123456;
public:
    int setkey(int value)
    {
        private_key = value;
    }
    int GetScore()
    {
        return private_key;
    }
};

void main()
{
    MyInfo* pMyInfo;
    pMyInfo = (MyInfo*)malloc(sizeof(MyInfo));

    printf("%d\n",  pMyInfo->GetScore());

    free(pMyInfo);
}
```

Comment: `malloc` just returns raw memory. No object springs to life there.

Comment: Add a constructor to this Struct 

`MyInfo()
 {
  std::cout << "Constructor Called  ";
 }`


with **malloc** no constructor is called, but **new** keyword is OK to write assigned  value of **private_key**

Answer (score 4):

Don't use `malloc`/`free` but rather `pMyInfo = new MyInfo()` and `delete pMyInfo`. Only `new` will call the constructor which initializes the value; only `delete` will call the destructor.

Regarding the comment, what is meant is, you can also have it on the stack, i.e. `MyInfo pMyInfo;`, i.e. not a pointer. That will automatically call the constructor and when it goes out of scope, the destructor.

Comment: Even better. Don't use raw dynamic allocation and deallocation. Prefer value semantics.

Answer (score 4):

```
int private_key = 123456;
```

This really is just a camouflaged constructor initialization which means it's the same as:

```
MyInfo() : private_key(123456) {}
```

Since `malloc` and friends are inherited from C and C has no classes (and thus no special member functions) whatsoever `malloc` and friends won't call these necessary special member functions to set up your object. The C++ equivalent `new` does however which is why you should always use `new` over `malloc` and `delete` over `free`.

---

But wait, there's more...

Actually, you shouldn't ever use `new` either, there are always better alternatives than using raw dynamic allocation. If you really need dynamic memory allocation then use `std::unique_ptr` or for multiple objects `std::vector` but most of the time you don't even need these ( there are tons of posts on here that explain  when dynamic allocation is a must, for all the other cases just use storage with automatic lifetime) all you need in this case is a local object:

```
MyInfo myInfo;
printf("%d\n",  myInfo.GetScore());
```

See how your code just got shorter, easier to maintain and cleaner to achieve the same?

Answer (score 0):

Don't mix `C` and `C++`

You should avoid `malloc/alloc` etc in `C++` and opt for `new` operator if you want to work with dynamically allocated objects.

Add a constructor to initialize the value

```
private;
    int private_key;

public:
    MyInfo () {
        private_key = 123456;
    }
```

And implement the main like

```
// without pointer
void main () {
    MyInfo myinfo;
    printf("%d\n", myinfo.GetScore());
}

// with pointer
void main () {
    MyInfo *myinfo = new MyInfo();
    printf("%d\n", myinfo->GetScore());
}
```

Comment: The constructor you added doesn't initialize the value, it assigns. And the OP used perfectly valid C++11 syntax to initialize the value with a default one.

Comment: @StoryTeller I was considering it as 4.3.2 or 4.9.9.3, my bad as I've never used C++11

Comment: N.P. I was just commenting on how you could improve the answer. If you make the constructor actually initialize the value, and get rid of the leak, this answer is worth an upvote.

Answer (score 0):

When you declare a pointer of type MyInfo, it does not mean that the object it points to will actually be your struct, it just assumes it will be.

When you do `malloc(sizeof(MyInfo))`, you simply allocate memory of the size which your struct might take, it does not create an object. Hence, when you try to do `GetScore()`, it accesses memory location which it assumes contains your `private_key`, but instead it simply contains garbage.

Answer (score 0):

Just for reference, it is possible to initialize an object in raw storage, but it would be overkill and rather stupid for this use case. As malloc only allocate raw memory and does not construct an object, you could use a placement new to build the object in a second time:

```
int main()      // I can't stand void main
{
    MyInfo* pMyInfo;
    pMyInfo = (MyInfo*)malloc(sizeof(MyInfo));  // only allocate raw memory
    new((void *) pMyInfo) MyInfo;               // construct the object

    std::cout << pMyInfo->GetScore() << std::endl;  // no reason for C printf here

    pMyInfo->~MyInfo(); // placement new requires explicit destructor call if not trivial
    free(pMyInfo);
    return 0;
}
```

**DO NOT DO THAT for such a simple case**. Placement new should only be used in very special cases where the allocation is not trivial, for example when you use share memory. But here the correct way is to simply use an automatic object:

```
int main()      // I can't stand void main
{
    MyInfo pMyInfo;

    std::cout << pMyInfo.GetScore() << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```